# How can I split the first and last name from one user input when they are separated by a comma?

Tags: c

I am trying to write some basic user input code where the I ask for first and last name in the form: first,lastname
and I would then store each name into string variables first and last? The issue is, the user can add as many spaces before or after the comma, and there can also be a comma before the first name.

Ex. valid inputs:  'John,smith'  ',>>John,>>Smith' ',John>>>,>>>smith'

The > are spaces, I think you get the idea.

I've been  trying to use scanf() but definitely running into issues with it.

Would I have to just use getchar() and go character by character until '\n', and if they are not a ' ' or ',' then copy it to the respective variable?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{   
   char first[50], last[50];

printf("Enter first name, last name: ");
scanf("%s,%s", &first, &last);      

printf("The name is %s %s.", first, last);

//input: john,smith -> the output would be "The name is john,smith  ."   
//                                                 (no 'last' stored) I'm not sure why?


return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use `fgets` to read the whole line, `strtok` to divide the line into tokens, and `strcpy` to copy the tokens into the `first` and `last` arrays.

Comment: `scanf` should basically not be used, it is both tricky to use, and a security risk (for buffer overflow attack). Your direct problem is that `%s` considers a comma as just another valid input, so you never get around to getting the second string. As advised above, `fgets` is both safe and simple, everything `scanf` is not.

Comment: scanf scans until first space or line break so coma is not separating inputs to two variables
you should ask for first name and last name separately or just use one character array and then searching array for coma taking a note of the index of coma and all values before coma are first name and after coma are last name (given there is no space character)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple implementation using `strchr` to find a `','` in `line` and change it to a null terminator, then using `strncpy` to copy into each of `first` and `last`.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define LINE_SIZE 256
#define NAME_SIZE 128

int main(void) {
    char line[LINE_SIZE];
    char first[NAME_SIZE], last[NAME_SIZE];

    fgets(line, LINE_SIZE, stdin);

    char *tok;

    if ((tok = strchr(line, ',')) != NULL) {
        *tok = '\0';
        strncpy(first, line, NAME_SIZE-1);
        strncpy(last, tok + 1, NAME_SIZE-1);

        printf("%s, %s\n", first, last);
    }
    else {
        printf("Comma not found.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, but please note `fgets()` reserves newline character at the end of the input string and you may need to chop it off from the last name. As a side note, `fgets()` reads at most one less characters than the specified size reserving the space for the null terminator. Then you can use the same size (say 256) for both array declaration and `fgets()`.